# removing css button outline ie 6.0, 7.0

Tags: css

is there any way to remove button `outline`  in ie 6.0, 7.0

dreamweaver giving error

Unsupported property: `outline` 
Affects: Internet Explorer 6.0, 7.0

Comment: check this: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/articles/css/remove-button-focus-outline-using-css/

Answer (score 1):

input.yourClass { outline:none; border:none; }