# Removing CSS Button Outline

Tags: html, css

I tried this example: [removing css button outline ie 6.0, 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701670/removing-css-button-outline-ie-6-0-7-0)

...by adding `outline:none;` and `border:none;` but that doesn't resolve the issue, as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vVNGw/

What do I do to get rid of that pesky little outline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing css button outline ie 6.0, 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701670/removing-css-button-outline-ie-6-0-7-0)

Comment: It looks correct in Chrome.  Is there any reason you can't use submit instead?

Comment: Are you using a reset style sheet? I can also confirm that there is no outline in IE7.

Comment: If a question doesn't have good answers, then [offer a bounty on it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), don't just ask it again.

Comment: Using FireFox 13.0, weird sometimes it shows, sometimes it doesn't, wondering if its a browser glitch.

Comment: @Quentin, this is the first time asking, thank you.

Comment: have you set these two properties to `0`?

Comment: There is no border showing in Chrome for me either

Comment: Make a screenshot of what you see and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at the jsfiddle example, it appears that there is no border. If you are talking about the grey inside the button surrounding the text, simply add "background:white;" to your code and it will be a button the same color as the background so that you only see the words

Answer (score 2):

try the solution mentioned in this article. http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/remove-button-focus-outline-using-css/

Answer (score -1):

You should not remove the outline from a button or a link when it's focused. This is an essential indication to disabled users and many others who want to know if what they intended to do has been understood by their browser and done (successfully clicking on the right button or not; visual indication of where they're when using the tab key because they can't or don't use a mouse)

See W3C WCAG 2.0 Technique named **[F78](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F78.html)**

> Failure due to styling element outlines and borders in a way that
>   removes or renders non-visible the visual focus indicator